# HTAccess url Rewriting Not working in PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess file and it has the following code. I am running my project on local system. Whenever I Open http://localhost/jobseeker/   it opens it but the css and js files are not implemented. When i checked their paths, it shows, http://localhost/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css  instead of http://localhost/jobseeker/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css. Plz let me know how i can solve this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# BAN USER BY IP
<Limit GET POST>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 123.63.30.165
</Limit>
```

Comment: Did you close the <IfModule> container?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happened. I had also edited that in the question @pokeybit

Comment: Remove `/` from `RewriteRule . /index.php`

Comment: Nothing happened @pokeybit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `/jobseeker/.htaccess` with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jobseeker/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Also add this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(assets/.*)$ /jobseeker/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I put the above code in .htaccess but I didn't get where to find DocumentRoot/.htaccess @anubhava

Comment: Sorry, but I am not getting it. @anubhava

Comment: I just want to know where to add RewriteRule ^(assets/.*)$ /jobseeker/$1 [L,NC,R=301] line

Comment: If `.htaccess` file doesn't exist in parent directory of `jobseeker` then you will need to create a new one.

Comment: I did that but the results are still the same.

Comment: It shows no result but using http://localhost/jobseeker/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css, it shows the file

Comment: Yes, it gives me a Internal Server Error

Comment: I had put code at https://jsfiddle.net/Lp2jpme9/1/ just for better viewing.
plz chck that is i m writing the correct code

Comment: That's **wrong**. Last rule I mentioned multiple times will go in **parent directory's** .htaccess of `jobseeker`. Are you sure you understand what is a directory and what is a parent directory?